# how to update nested Map in dart flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Map<String,dynamic> serviceData = { 
'Hair Service': 
       {'simple hair cut' : 
            { 'price': 100,'duration': 30,},
        },
       {'shampoo + hair cut' : 
            { 'price': 100,'duration': 30,},
        },

//       {'new Service Name' : 
//          { 'price': new price,'duration': new duration,},
//      },

   'Hair styling':
        {'simple' : 
            { 'price': 100,'duration': 30,},
        },
       {'with conditioning' : 
            { 'price': 100,'duration': 30,},
        },
//       {'new Service Name' : 
//          { 'price': new price,'duration': new duration,},
//      },
}
```

I want to add/edit a "new service" in both these 'hair Service' and 'hair Style'

tried `serviceData.update()` but did not worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
serviceData["Hair Service"]["new Service Name"] = { 'price': new price,'duration': new duration,};

serviceData["Hair styling"]["new Service Name"] = { 'price': new price,'duration': new duration,};
```

or if its same object:

```
serviceData["Hair Service"]["new Service Name"] = { 'price': new price,'duration': new duration,};
serviceData["Hair Styling"]["new Service Name"] = serviceData["Hair Service"]["new Service Name"];
```